# How to delete a question with too many and/or upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

How can we delete a question I asked before at Stack Overflow, which has lots of up votes?

If I try to delete it, it shows this warning:

> Sorry, this question cannot be deleted: too many existing answers, or upvoted/accepted answers

Comment: Which question?

Comment: numbers of my question asked before  are 42  and I want delete some of them,,,,,,,,,these questions reside my profile ,,

Comment: You might consider deleting some of your answers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to plead your case with the moderators - flag the question for moderator attention and write your reason for requesting deletion.

Obviously, it is reasonable to believe that the question will *not* be deleted exactly for the reasons the warning message conveys. However, if you plead your case with a moderator and the reasons for deletion are deemed acceptable, then a moderator can vote to have it deleted.

**NOTE:**
I viewed your questions on SO and I personally don't think you will have a lot of luck asking for them to be deleted. Even your closed questions (dupes or whatever) add *some* value to the site. Asking for them to be deleted just because you want to thin the number of questions asked will most likely not happen. In addition, any up-voted questions that get deleted will affect your rep score once a recalc has been performed.